# How to specify packet size in Infinispan?

Tags: infinispan

Is there a way to specify packet-size in an infinispan server while we are using hotrod protocol for client/server data transmission.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HotRod protocol uses TCP connection for communication. Therefore, the stream is split into packets according to your OS settings. Especially this is affected by MTU size on your network interface.